# Have you ever used kon-boot?

Tags: hacking, password-recovery, live-cd

Has anyone here ever used [kon-boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/)? I guess it may work because of the few blog posts about it but I feel kinda concerned and am interested at hearing experiences from anyone who have used multiple times with no side effects.

I am slightly worried for any direct memory altering it tries to do.

I am also worried if this will do its job fine to hide the fact it puts in a low level trojan or if the author planned to do anything like that in a future release as it looks like closed source from the site.

Also I don't intend to gain illegal access but I find these sort of things very useful for my box of live discs I take every where, just in case.

[OT: Other question that me be of interest to readers here](https://serverfault.com/questions/428/what-is-the-best-way-to-gain-access-when-the-password-is-unknown)

Answer (score 1):

I've used it successfully on a test Ubuntu machine, never managed to get it running in Windows mode.  There are plenty of other ways of gaining access to a machine without passwords, all tried and tested and mostly open-sourced, and so there's no real reason to use Konboot IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have more to lose then to gain. Don't use it if you're worried about your network.

I would not rely on the opinion of anyone who could not audit source code.

If you wanted to be adventurous you could use it on an isolated system, then monitor that system's traffic on the swtich/router.

Answer (score 0):

Kon Boot is perfectly safe. A new commercial version 1.1 is out, it can be obtained at www.kryptoslogic.com . It is a California based company, and they back and support the product entirely. Some discount coupons for it laying around the net, but still cheap at $15 bucks.